# Custom Live Boot PXE ISO Script

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bash, dhcp, pxe-boot

Currently I am using an open source PC auditing software called Open-Audit to audit PCs my company receives off lease from school districts. The software uses snmap to pull hardware information over a subnet and saves it on the server. The problem I am having is that the majority of these computers are on a school domain and without the group policy credential snmap cannot pull the hardware info. To get around this I am creating a custom Ubuntu Live boot iso that will be stored on a PXE boot server. When the PC boots into PXE the user will select 'Audit' from a list, boot the PC into Ubuntu, the Bash audit script will run in the Ubuntu init startup script, load the information to the server, and exit out of the liveboot. I'm nearing completion but I'm getting hung up on the theory of one part and am hoping someone might be able to clarify this for me. One of the developers of the software pointed me in the right direction to doing all of this and at the end of his email he wrote

"Set the "url" variable to http://openaudit/ which would need to be     resolvable via DNS on the PXE network and point to your Open-AudIT server"

I already have a pxeboot server set up on the same server that stores the auditing software, and have set the variable properly in the audit script itself.. Can someone clarify what this might look like within the DHCP.conf file? the Open Audit software is stored in /var/www/html on a LAMP stack

Thanks for your help in advance and please let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"url" is a BASH variable within you audit script. In your case you should manually define it as the IP of your PXE server. That's it.

If your PXE server is also your DHCP server then you can add some BASH script lines for automatically defining the variable value from the DHCP server IP address avoiding this way the needed manual definition.

Comment: Ah! I get it. I believe I misread his sentence and was hung up on the wrong thing. Thanks for your help!